# Cannot play track from Spotify

Tags: android, spotify

I want to integrate **Spotify** to my application but every time I launch it I get an error. I tried their beginners guide, but same issue happened again.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    // Check if result comes from the correct activity
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);
        if (response.getType() == AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN) {
            Config playerConfig = new Config(this, response.getAccessToken(), CLIENT_ID);
            Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new SpotifyPlayer.InitializationObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onInitialized(SpotifyPlayer spotifyPlayer) {
                    mPlayer = spotifyPlayer;
                    mPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(MainActivity.this);
                    mPlayer.addNotificationCallback(MainActivity.this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I used break point it was able to stop inside inner class, but after that `onLoginFailed(int i)` method was executed with parameter 9. What does it mean? What I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a premium account?

Comment: We were experiencing some issues today while the huge DNS attack against DynDNS was causing problems all over the internet. Can you still reproduce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify is under a DDOS attack at the moment. Rather DYN the company that hosts their DNS/Traffic. Read about it [here](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/21/major-websites-across-east-coast-knocked-out-in-apparent-ddos-attack.html). Also, a quick tweet from the company themselves [here](https://twitter.com/SpotifyStatus?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor)